# $firebaseSimpleLogin: some errors are not fired

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebasesimplelogin

I'm testing $firebaseSimpleLogin authentication.
I did set up oAuth accounts for Google, Facebook and Twitter, and them all work very smootly.
I only noticed a little issue (I can't tell if it's a real problem...): if you forget (or voluntarily avoid) enabling an origin domain (in firebaseio.com console), the authentication correctly fails, but no error is returned:

```
app.factory('Auth', function ($firebaseSimpleLogin) {
  var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
  var auth = $firebaseSimpleLogin(ref);
  var provider = 'google'; // any social provider will fit

  auth.$login(provider, {
    rememberMe: true,
    scope:
      (provider === 'google') ?
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile' : 
      (provider === 'facebook') ? 'email' : null,
      preferRedirect: false
  }).then(
    function (authUser) {
      console.info('user authenticated');
    },
    function (error) {
      /* ======================================================
       * YOU DON'T GET HERE IF CURRENT DOMAIN IS NOT ENABLED...
       * ====================================================== */
      console.error('social login with ' + provider +
                    ' provider failed: ' + error.message);
    }
  );
});
```

Is this a bug?

**UPDATE**:
@HarishR: do you mean something like this?

```
auth.$login(provider, {}
).then(
  function (success) {},
  function (error) {}
).catch(error) {
  console.error('social login with ' + provider +
                ' provider failed: ' + error);
};
```

It gives `syntax error`...
For @HashirR this is the error details:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { auth.js:94
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'AuthCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/ng/areq?p0=AuthCtrl&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined
    at http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:78:12
    at assertArg (http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1443:11)
    at assertArgFn (http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1453:3)
    at http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:7131:9
    at http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:6538:34
    at forEach (http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:330:20)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:6525:11)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:5986:15)
    at publicLinkFn (http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:5891:30)
    at link (http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:19396:38)
```

Comment: can you try if .catch works $http().then(success, error).catch(error);

Comment: thanks... see question update...

Comment: can you provide the error also in the update...

Comment: added syntax error in question...

Comment: error says `AuthCtrl` is undefined, which has nothing to do with .then & .catch... comment out that code and try to solve that issue first.

Comment: AuthCtrl is the name of the controller where auth.$login is... The error is introduced with the catch() code, without it everything works smoothly... Probably you can't use a catch() after a then()...